# MVC (Entity framework) Saving ID changes from "Create View" to SQL database table

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I need solution for my problem. Got 1 database with 3 tables (with primary keys and identity (1,1) and 3 foreign keys) I will post diagram bellow.

[image]

[image]

My dropdown lists are connected if I choose Country it will just list me states from that country.
What I want to do is when i pick Country and state that automatically save their id in my table Contact. Because If I choose country and state Id manually it works otherwise I got error. Here are my controller code and Create View.

```
 public ActionResult Create()

        {
            List<Country> CountryList = db.Countries.ToList();
            ViewBag.CountryList = new SelectList(CountryList, "CountryId", "CountryName");
            return View();
        }

       

        


        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]

        public ActionResult Create(CountryStateContactViewModel csvm)


        {

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)

            {

                return View(csvm);

            }
            Contact model = new Contact() { CountryId = csvm.CountryId, StateId = csvm.StateId, ContactId = csvm.ContactsId, ImeOsobe = csvm.PersonName, PrezimeOsobe = csvm.PersonLastName, Komentar = csvm.Comment, Email = csvm.Email, Aktivan = csvm.Active, kcbr = csvm.kcbr, KucniBroj = csvm.HouseNumber, NazivUlice = csvm.StreetName, NazivNaselja = csvm.SettlementName, PostanskiBroj = csvm.PostalCode, KontaktBroj=csvm.ContactNumber};
            db.Contacts.Add(model);

            try
            {
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException db)
            {
                Exception raise = db;
                foreach (var validationErrors in db.EntityValidationErrors)
                {
                    foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                    {
                        string message = string.Format("{0}:{1}",
                            validationErrors.Entry.Entity.ToString(),
                            validationError.ErrorMessage);
                        
                        raise = new InvalidOperationException(message, raise);
                    }
                }
                throw raise;

            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");


}
```

And my CreateView

```
@model AkvizicijeApp_3_6.Models.CountryStateContactViewModel

<h2>Create</h2>
<br /><br />
<div class="container">
    <div class="form-group">


        @if (ViewBag.CountryList != null)
        {

            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CountryId, ViewBag.CountryList as SelectList, "--Select Country--", new { @class = "form-control" })

        }

    </div>
    <div class="form-group">


        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.StateId, new SelectList(" "), "--Select State--", new { @class = "form-control" })





    </div>
</div>


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>CountryStateContactViewModel</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CountryId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CountryId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CountryId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StateId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StateId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StateId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PostalCode, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PostalCode, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PostalCode, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SettlementName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SettlementName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SettlementName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StreetName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StreetName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StreetName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.HouseNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.HouseNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.HouseNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.kcbr, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.kcbr, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.kcbr, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Active, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Active)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Active, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PersonName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PersonName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PersonName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PersonLastName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PersonLastName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PersonLastName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ContactNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ContactNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ContactNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Comment, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Comment, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Comment, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#CountryId").change(function () {
            $.get("/Home/GetStateList", { CountryId: $("#CountryId").val() }, function (data) {
                $("#StateId").empty();
                $.each(data, function (index, row) {
                    $("#StateId").append("<option value=`" + row.StateId + "`>" + row.StateName + "</option>")
                });
            });
        })
    });
</script>
```

```
public class CountryStateContactViewModel
    {

        
        public int CountryId { get; set; }

        
        public int StateId { get; set; }
        public string StateName { get; set; }
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int ContactsId { get; set; }
        public int PostalCode { get; set; }
        public string SettlementName { get; set; }
        public string StreetName { get; set; }
        public string HouseNumber { get; set; }
        public string kcbr { get; set; }
        public bool Active { get; set; }
        public string PersonName { get; set; }
        public string PersonLastName { get; set; }
        public string ContactNumber { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Comment { get; set; }

    }
```

If u need more information just tell me and I will update my question. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

Move your @Html.DropDownListFor inside @using (Html.BeginForm()). and remove StateId and CountryId manual input fields @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CountryId) & @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StateId). In other words replace "Html.EditorFor" with HtmlDropdownlistFor from above.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<div class="form-horizontal">
     <h4>CountryStateContactViewModel</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CountryId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CountryId, ViewBag.CountryList as SelectList, "--Select Country--", new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CountryId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StateId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.StateId, new SelectList(" "), "--Select State--", new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StateId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PostalCode, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PostalCode, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PostalCode, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SettlementName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SettlementName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SettlementName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StreetName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StreetName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StreetName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.HouseNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.HouseNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.HouseNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.kcbr, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.kcbr, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.kcbr, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Active, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="checkbox">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Active)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Active, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PersonName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PersonName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PersonName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PersonLastName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PersonLastName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PersonLastName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ContactNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ContactNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ContactNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Comment, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Comment, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Comment, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

Comment: I did it like you said and everything is ok in form now, except for saving my data, when I go on create button, just nothing happens

Comment: And If I Copy paste your code it require me to input number as state "The field StateId must be a number."

Comment: could you publish your CountryStateContactViewModel  class

Comment: How do you add StateId values? DropdownlistFor generates <select> with <options>.. Please make sure there is a value inside option like: <option value="1">State1</option>, check your generated HTML code with code inspector

Comment: StateId values generate automatically by themselves since I made it identity (1,1) in sql table.